# What is the difference between F10 and F11 keys in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm new in C#. I hit a breakpoint and pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Which key should be use for compilation?

Please help me out. Can you explain me what this keys does?

Answer (score 43):

<kbd>F10</kbd> ("step over") does not descend any further into the call stack.  It moves to the next line of the current function.

<kbd>F11</kbd> ("step into") drills down into the function being called.

```
void function1()
{
    function2();
    function3();
}
```

If you hit a breakpoint on `function2()`, <kbd>F10</kbd> will advance to the line `function3()`.  <kbd>F11</kbd> will advance to the first line inside `function2`.

Comment: Shift F11 = "Step Out"; I enjoy this debug hotkey very much too.

Answer (score 4):

**If you are an absolute beginner with Visual Studio, say Visual Studio 2017** :

The function keys F10 and F11 helps to follow the execution path in the
code and thus helps to examine the intermediate results and debug the
code.

You need to put a 'break point' to any line in your own code (inside a method (function)). Before executing  the program, just CLICK at the leftmost border side of  the code window corresponding to a code statement from which you need to start debugging. You can put multiple break points in your code.

Now Execute(run) the program, it will come to an automatic hault at your first break point. Now keep on pressing F10 to move from one statement to another to proceed with the execution of the program (in sequential order).

But if you are currently at a statement which includes a function (method) call such as `FindSum(a,b);`  and now if you press F11, it will take you to the fist line in the function `FindSum(a,b)` and proceed. Note that pressing F10 when your current statement involves a function call, it will just execute the function (without taking you to the statements in the function body) and move to the next line in your code.

In short, pressing F11 will take you to every line including your function body, but F10 allows to move from one line to the the immediate next line.

Answer (score 1):

An example. Suppose we have the below code piece

using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var add = AddFunction(10,20);
            Console.WriteLine(add);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

```
    static int AddFunction(int a,int b)
    {
            return a+b; 
    }
}
```

}

Now set a break-point at the var add = AddFunction(10,20);

If we perform a Step Over(or F10), then after that line, the control will go to the next line which is Console.WriteLine(add); followed by Console.ReadKey(); and lastly } and finally returns a value of 0 to OS.

If we perform a Step Into (or F11), then after var add = AddFunction(10,20); , the control will go into the called function implementation of AddFunciton which is return a+b and after that Console.WriteLine(add); and so on.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F10</kbd> just debug step by step .
if u can call any function in this or any system class then <kbd>F10</kbd> not go to defination part of  that class or method, they just flow in step by step but if u can use <kbd>F11</kbd> for debuging then it can go at the defination part of the function or class.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F10</kbd> -> Execute the next line of code but not follow execution through any function calls (Step Over).

<kbd>F11</kbd> -> Execute code one statement at a time, following execution into function calls (Step Into).

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>F10</kbd>=>Step Over(Go and execute every line of the function)

<kbd>F11</kbd>=>Step Into (Go and execute the every function)

Comment: There are three other answers from three years ago. Please, make sure that your answer adds something significant to already existing ones.