# Calling a private void function from a button click method

Tags: c#, function, class, buttonclick

I am trying to call a private void function from a button click method . The value of selectedChoice is fetched from combo box . I debugged and found out that the value of selectedChoice is being fetched properly and it is even going inside If condition inside the button click method. Its just that the functions are not being call .

Every method is inside the class Form1.

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {     
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(selectedChoice == "ABC")
            {
                Function1();
                Function2();
            }
```

The combo box code -

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex!=0)
            {
                selectedChoice = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            }
        }
```

The functions I am trying to call are simply defined as

```
 private void Function1()
  { 
      //do something

   }
```

Comment: If the debugging show it reach the if block, then keep going into it, use the [F11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15584171/529282). Then you'll find out if the problem is actually on Function1() or somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to perform a compare opertion

```
selectedChoice == "ABC"
```

the

```
 ==
```

Operator shall not be used for string. This operator will check if the id of the element and the comparer are equals. Please use

```
selectedChoice.Equals("ABC")
```

instead.

Nevertheless the Methods are called using this code:

```
private string selectedChoice = "ABC";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(selectedChoice.Equals("ABC"))
        {
            Function1();
            Function2();
        }
    }

    private void Function2()
    {

    }

    private void Function1()
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex!=0)
        {
            selectedChoice = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please make sure, that the selectedItem with "ABC" is not the first one in the combobox

Comment: This code above is working in my environment. Do you have any optimization, Attributes configured, which may lead to the behaviour you describe?